# Userscript not detecting url change on some pages (e.g. Facebook)

Tags: javascript, url, dom-events, userscripts, http-redirect

I'm trying to write a userscript to redirect the URL of certain webpages, including Facebook. My (limited) understanding is that there is no direct way for a userscript to tell when the URL changes (there's `window.onurlchange` but that only works in Tampermonkey. I am using [Firemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firemonkey/) on Firefox). I have my script set to run at `document-start`, but when a webpage navigates to a new URL, it seems like this doesn't always run (possibly when it's in the same domain?)

I've read into some workarounds here on stackoverflow, which you can see in the code of my userscript below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             Redirect
// @match            https://www.facebook.com/groups/*
// @exclude          https://www.facebook.com/groups/*/*/
// @run-at           document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function fireRedirect() {
  let mHref = window.location.href;
  if ( !mHref.includes("sorting_setting") ) {
    window.location = mHref.concat("?sorting_setting=CHRONOLOGICAL");
  }
}

window.onpopstate = fireRedirect();

new MutationObserver(mutationsList => {
  console.log(mutationsList[0].target.textContent);
  fireRedirect();
})
.observe(
  document.querySelector('title'),
  {subtree: true, childList: true}
);

fireRedirect();
```

This will fire if I navigate manually to a URL like [www.facebook.com/groups/examplegroupname](http://www.facebook.com/groups/examplegroupname) from the addressbar, but if I'm on the main [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) home feed, and I click a link to go to [www.facebook.com/groups/examplegroupname](http://www.facebook.com/groups/examplegroupname), the script does not run. If I simply refresh the page, *then* it will run. (That's also how I know the @exclude isn't the issue.)

Is there some better way to handle this?

Comment: See: [`window.onurlchange`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:window.onurlchange). Likely the most reliable way to watch for URL changes.

Comment: @double-beep you may notice in the question I actually mention onurlchange as an option, however it *only* works on Tampermonkey. That's why I tried the universally compatible techniques in the script (`onpopstate` and a Mutation Observer on the document `title` value).